# How to delete mongodb collections based on their age or created date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a bunch of mongodb **collections** as the below and they are created on the different date and use the date as their names:

```
2015-06-01
2015-06-02
2015-06-03
...
2015-06-30
total 30 collections
```

Let's say I **ONLY** want to keep the latest **10** collections **today** and **today** is **2015-06-30**. Based on their names, you should know I only want to keep

```
2015-06-21
2015-06-22
...
2015-06-30
10 collections
```

Then tomorrow is **2015-07-01**, I still want to keep the latest 10 collections and at the same time, `2015-07-01` collection is created.

So I have to delete **2015-06-21** to keep the total collection number equals to 10.

Then I will repeat this process every day to keep total 10 days collections in the mongodb.

How to achieve that using `Mongoose API` and `Node.JS` (JavaScript)?

`setInterval` and `db.dropCollection` will be used, I assume.

Comment: 1) Check - whether you want to add a new collection called the current date. If necessary, add; 2) Get the sorted ascending list of collections named by date; Check - if the number of elements is greater than 10, then remove the first extra collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So presuming you have a list of collections in your database by your naming of the date like so:

```
[ '2015-01-01',
  '2015-01-02',
  '2015-01-03',
  '2015-01-04',
  '2015-01-05',
  '2015-01-06',
  '2015-01-07',
  '2015-01-08',
  '2015-01-09',
  '2015-01-10',
  '2015-01-11',
  '2015-01-12' ]
```

Then if you want to remove all but the last 10 collections that are older than "today" then you would take this approach:

```
var async = require('async'),
    crontab = require('node-crontab'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/crontest');

var conn = mongoose.connection;

conn.once("open",function() {

  var jobId = crontab.scheduleJob("0 0 * * *",function() {

    var today = new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10);

    var db = conn.db;

    db.listCollections({ "name": { "$lt": today  } })
      .toArray(function(err,items) {
        var names = items.map(function(item) {
          return item.name;
        })

        async.eachLimit(
          names.slice(0,names.length-10),10,function(name,callback) {
            db.dropCollection(name,callback);
          },function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('done');
          }
        );

      });

  });

});
```

I'm just putting the whole thing in [`node-crontab`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-crontab) but shedule however you want.

The first thing you need to do is grab a handle to underlying native [`Db`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html) object from your mongoose connection:

```
var conn = mongoose.connection;

{ ... }

    var db = conn.db;
```

And make sure that the connection is "actually open" when you run. It will be if other "mongoose methods" on your models have actually invoked, but really you should be sure, hence:

```
conn.once("open",function() {
   // everything in here
});
```

Then it's simply just a matter of getting the ISOString for todays date in order to apply to the "filter" query called on [`.listCollections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections) which is going to return your collection names ( and other properties ) based on that filter. You always don't want to remove the current day.

Then it's just a matter of "slicing" that array in order to get only those collections that are not in the last 10 items. So slice with `.length-10` to get the position to get from the starting index of the array.

Then just pass those into a loop, using [`async.eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) because the [`.dropCollection()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#dropCollection) call is async, also to "limit" how many tasks to run in parallel.

Once those are done then the job is complete and the collections are removed. Also there is no point in "creating" a collection ( add if you want ) as MongoDB will just do that as soon as you write something to your new name.